# Ef CTP5: Linq query help

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I am trying to load a custom object using linq from entity data context. Here is my code

```
from category in _db.GetQueryable<DataModels.Category>()
 select new Category
 {
   Id = category.Id,
   Name = category.Name,
   CreatedBy = category.CreatedBy.HasValue ? new Login { Id = category.CreatedBy ?? Guid.Empty } : null
 }

//Note: GetQueryable<DataModels.Category> actually use Set<DataModels.Category>() in DataContext class.
```

But it generates following error:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'CodeOnly.EF.DomainModels.Login'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.
```

But above code always work if I use Linq2Sql.

Any idea how I can achieve this in EF5 code only scenario.

Comment: Just a wild guess here but do you get the same error if you moved the `CreatedBy` expression into a separate `let` clause?  That way you move that out of the projection.

Comment: CreatedBy here is a property of category datamodel(A nullable GUID). So not sure how "let" is useful here

Comment: What type is the `CreatedBy` property on the `Category` class?  If is a `Login` (as indicated by you setting it's value to a `new Login`), or is it a guid (as indicated by `Id = category.CreatedBy ?? Guid.Empty`) ?

Comment: The error mentions that it doesn't work in that context.  I'm guessing that could mean _only_ the projection.  Maybe trying it like this: `from category in _db.GetQueryable<DataModels.Category>() let createdBy = (category.CreatedBy.HasValue ? new Login { Id = category.CreatedBy ?? Guid.Empty } : null) select new Category { Id = category.Id, Name = category.Name, CreatedBy = createdBy };`

Comment: @jeff: Thanks I tried that but giving same error

Answer (score 0):

You probably simply need to get the `Category` data out of the database before you start projecting it into custom types.

Only get what you need, but then call `ToList()` on your collection to perform execution and get it out of the database.  Then you'll be free to project into whatever type you want.

```
var items = _db.GetQueryable<DataModels.Category>().ToList();
from category in items
select new Category  
{    
    Id = category.Id,
    Name = category.Name,
    CreatedBy = category.CreatedBy.HasValue 
        ? new Login { Id = category.CreatedBy ?? Guid.Empty } : null
}
```

**edit**: as new information comes to light, new ideas spring forth - try this one:

```
partial class Category
{
    public Category(int id, string name, Guid? createdByGuid)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        CreatedBy = createdByGuid.HasValue ? new Login { Id = createdByGuid.Value } : null;
    }
}

var items = _db.GetQueryable<DataModels.Category>().ToList();
from category in items
select new Category(category.Id, category.Name, category.CreatedBy)
```

I also wonder why in your original question you are checking the Guid? *twice* for null (`HasValue` and `??`) - however I don't think that is what is causing you problems.

Comment: But I want to return IQueryable from my Repository. So that my service layer can modify the query on different situation without executing the query.

If I call ToList then query will be executed at that time and any more filtering will be placed in memory. If I have 2000 records then I don't want to do this.

Comment: That's fair enough, then perhaps you should do this projection further along the line - in your service layer?  I think the problem is that the repository can't instantiate new objects (`new Login`), so you need to make that happen above your database.

Comment: I am using DataModel in my repository and DomainModel in service layer. As DataModel is presistant object so I don't want to pass it to service layer. Just want to pass non-presistant lighweight domain model or you can say POCO. Thats why I am after a solution to convert my datamodels to domainmodel from repository. This works fine with LINQ2SQL but facing problem with EF5.

Comment: If you try this suggestion then it will at least identify where the problems exists.  You also haven't responded to my earlier comment regarding the `CreatedBy` property and what type it should be.

Comment: In case of DataModel [CreatedBy] is Guid?
In case of DomainModel [CreatedBy] is Login instance

Comment: You should create a Guid? on the DomainModel object so you can store the value, and then project it into the Login object later on when you are away from the database.  Don't mark the Guid as serializable, or better yet make it private.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: If createdBy of datamodel is null then createdBy property (Login object) of domainmodel should be null not a login object with empty guid. I don't want to change my domain model just because of data model.

Comment: I've edited it *again* - if you don't at try this answer and give some feedback then I give up!  Meanwhile, if you don't want a login object with empty Guid then why are you checking & assigning it `Login { Id = category.CreatedBy ?? Guid.Empty }`